# How to define workspace as input for GP tool in order to select from list CAD layers as the second input?

Tags: python, arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.1, geoprocessing

How to define workspace (folder) as input for gp tool in order to select CAD layers as the second input **that will be obtained from the first input**?

Comment: What is your first input?  Are you wanting to convert the CAD layers to GIS layers?

Comment: No, my first input is workspace (Folder), and my second input is CAD Choice list from the current workspace (First input)

Comment: What are you wanting to do with the CAD dwg within your python script?

Comment: I want to use summery statistics on some layers from workspace folder in order to get catalog of quentits for each layer at each CAD

Comment: So, summary stats on the CAD point, line, and polygon layers?  Are you planning on converting these layers to GIS to perform the stats?

Comment: Yes , i want to count how many polyline in each Layer for each DWG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within the ArcGIS script/gp tool there is no easy way to fetch '.dwg' files (obtained from or direct filter) from a workspace parameter within the script tool parameters tab.  You may build that search functionality though into your python script logic, for example:

```
import os, arcpy

inputDir = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)

# walk through inputDir
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(inputDir):

        # iterate through all files in directory
        for f in files:
            if f.endswith(".dwg"):
                dwgPolyline = root + '\\' + f + '\\polyline'
                # do something else
```

Answer (score 1):

You can update the picklist of the parameter in the updateParameters function. This should be possible using a normal script (added to a normal toolbox), but in my opinion it's much easier in a python toolbox.

In the updateParameters function, you can iterate through the given directory similar to how artwork21 suggested and then add the appropriate files to the valid choices of your parameter.

*Note, this code should be contained in a python toolbox file (*.pyt), not a normal python file (*.py):*

```
import os
import arcpy

class TestTool(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.label = "Test Tool"

    def getParameterInfo(self):
        pInputWorkspace = arcpy.Parameter()
        pInputWorkspace.name = 'input_ws'
        pInputWorkspace.displayName = 'Input Workspace'
        pInputWorkspace.parameterType = 'Required'
        pInputWorkspace.datatype = 'Folder'
        pInputWorkspace.direction = 'Input'

        pInputDrawing = arcpy.Parameter()
        pInputDrawing.name = 'input_dwg'
        pInputDrawing.displayName = 'Input Drawing'
        pInputDrawing.parameterType = 'Required'
        pInputDrawing.datatype = 'String'
        pInputDrawing.direction = 'Input'

        pOutput = arcpy.Parameter()
        pOutput.name = 'output_p'
        pOutput.displayName = 'Output Value'
        pOutput.datatype = 'Boolean'
        pOutput.parameterType = 'Derived'
        pOutput.direction = 'Output'

        return [pInputWorkspace, pInputDrawing, pOutput]

    def updateParameters(self, parameters):
        pInputWorkspace = parameters[0]
        pInputDrawing = parameters[1]
        if(pInputWorkspace.altered):
            dwglist = []
            for root, dirs, files in os.walk(pInputWorkspace.ValueAsText):
                for f in files:
                    if f.lower().endswith(".dwg"):
                        dwglist.append(str(f))
            pInputDrawing.filter.list = dwglist

    def execute(self, parameters, messages):
        # do stuff
        pass

class Toolbox(object):
    def __init__(self):
        """Test toolbox description"""
        self.label = "Test Toolbox"
        self.alias = ""

        self.tools = [TestTool]
```